# Tikz: Multi-line text in the node description

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, multline

I use tikz to create pictures in latex. 
My picture consists of set of nodes. Every node has its own text inside the node, for example, "This node is valuable":

```
  \node (mynode) [mystyle,right=of anothernode] {This node is valuable};
```

When I compile the document I see the description as one line.

**This node is valuable**

Is it possible to split the line into multiple lines? Like this:

**This node**

**is**

**valuable**

Which commands should one apply in order to achieve this?

Comment: I'm still having trouble with the same thing. Even trying the suggestions here.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

A short example derived from the [pgf/tikZ](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) 2.10 manual.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[%
    >=stealth,
    node distance=3cm,
    on grid,
    auto
  ]
    \node[state] (A)              {A};
    \node        (B) [right of=A,fill=blue!25,text width=3cm]{This is a demonstration text for showing how line breaking works.};;
    \path[->] (A) edge (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For text alignment there is also the `align` option.

---

[image]

Comment: +1 I like the idea: constraint text area with "text width" option and that is how the sentence is split. Thanks!

Comment: You can also use the package `varwidth` to constrain the node dynamically. When you say `text width=3cm` the node will always have space for 3cm of text, which makes nodes with little text too big. The `varwidth` environment grows with the text up to the given width and only then constrains.

Answer (score 81):

Yes, you can have more than one node part (for more information, refer to the TikZ manual 48.6, p. 447, pgf/tikz 2.10).

A simple example would be like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
\node (test) [rectangle, draw] {this node \\ has \\ four \\lines};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like your proposal: it is simple and fast to check, however, I have got the following error: "! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/align' and I am going to". Is it something connected to configuration? Moreover, when I delete "align=center" I have got a rectangle with all words in one line :( What could be the issue?

Comment: @Tim - I think you are not using the up to date version of pgf (which is 2.10).... Simply exchange `ever text node part/.style={align=center}` with `text centered` and it should work!

Comment: Let me note --since I just got bitten by this-- that if you leave out the "align", you don't get the line breaking.  (This is counter-intuitive to me but is what I saw.)

Answer (score 74):

You can just put a simple tabular environment, if you want to control the break. For instance, use

```
\node (mynode) [mystyle,right=of anothernode] {\begin{tabular}{c} This node \\ is \\ valuable \end{tabular}};
```

Comment: +1 Because I can still do stuff like `\textbf{..}` and so on..