# Database shape in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create a database shape in tikz that looks something like this:

[image]

I need the two arcs in the middle, so I cannot directly use `cylinder`, as suggested in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123854/display-database-instance-relationship-with-tikz).

Ideally, I would like to start from the `cylinder` shape and just add a few arcs, but I cannot figure out how to do this?
Is the code of the `cylinder` shape available somewhere? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

I have looked at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65642/use-a-custom-shape-as-a-building-block) that asks how to create a shape for a camera, but it is quite far from what I want.

Comment: The `cylinder` shape is defined in [this file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/tex/pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex) starting from line 4021.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think you need to define a new shape for this, unless you also want to use the border anchor. If you do, please let me know.

For simple usage you could use the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    database/.style={
        path picture={
            \draw (0, 1.5*\database@segmentheight) circle [x radius=\database@radius,y radius=\database@aspectratio*\database@radius];
            \draw (-\database@radius, 0.5*\database@segmentheight) arc [start angle=180,end angle=360,x radius=\database@radius, y radius=\database@aspectratio*\database@radius];
            \draw (-\database@radius,-0.5*\database@segmentheight) arc [start angle=180,end angle=360,x radius=\database@radius, y radius=\database@aspectratio*\database@radius];
            \draw (-\database@radius,1.5*\database@segmentheight) -- ++(0,-3*\database@segmentheight) arc [start angle=180,end angle=360,x radius=\database@radius, y radius=\database@aspectratio*\database@radius] -- ++(0,3*\database@segmentheight);
        },
        minimum width=2*\database@radius + \pgflinewidth,
        minimum height=3*\database@segmentheight + 2*\database@aspectratio*\database@radius + \pgflinewidth,
    },
    database segment height/.store in=\database@segmentheight,
    database radius/.store in=\database@radius,
    database aspect ratio/.store in=\database@aspectratio,
    database segment height=0.1cm,
    database radius=0.25cm,
    database aspect ratio=0.35,
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]
        \node[database,label=below:some label] {};
        \node[database,label=below:some label,database radius=1cm,database segment height=0.5cm] at (3,0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` are necessary to use macros with `@` in them. It is not really needed here, but I prefer to use it to keep macros readable and to prevent you from overwriting them somewhere without using the `pgf` keys.

This examples results in:

[image]

### Edit

As requested in the comments, with the following code you can set a style for all three segments separately. You can use `database top segment={<style>}`, `database middle segment={<style>}`, and `database bottom segment={<style>}` for this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=2mm]{standalone}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    database top segment style/.style={draw},
    database middle segment style/.style={draw},
    database bottom segment style/.style={draw},
    database/.style={
        path picture={
            \path [database bottom segment style]
                (-\db@r,-0.5*\db@sh) 
                -- ++(0,-1*\db@sh) 
                arc [start angle=180, end angle=360,
                    x radius=\db@r, y radius=\db@ar*\db@r]
                -- ++(0,1*\db@sh)
                arc [start angle=360, end angle=180,
                    x radius=\db@r, y radius=\db@ar*\db@r];
            \path [database middle segment style]
                (-\db@r,0.5*\db@sh) 
                -- ++(0,-1*\db@sh) 
                arc [start angle=180, end angle=360,
                    x radius=\db@r, y radius=\db@ar*\db@r]
                -- ++(0,1*\db@sh)
                arc [start angle=360, end angle=180,
                    x radius=\db@r, y radius=\db@ar*\db@r];
            \path [database top segment style]
                (-\db@r,1.5*\db@sh) 
                -- ++(0,-1*\db@sh) 
                arc [start angle=180, end angle=360,
                    x radius=\db@r, y radius=\db@ar*\db@r]
                -- ++(0,1*\db@sh)
                arc [start angle=360, end angle=180,
                    x radius=\db@r, y radius=\db@ar*\db@r];
            \path [database top segment style]
                (0, 1.5*\db@sh) circle [x radius=\db@r, y radius=\db@ar*\db@r];
        },
        minimum width=2*\db@r + \pgflinewidth,
        minimum height=3*\db@sh + 2*\db@ar*\db@r + \pgflinewidth,
    },
    database segment height/.store in=\db@sh,
    database radius/.store in=\db@r,
    database aspect ratio/.store in=\db@ar,
    database segment height=0.1cm,
    database radius=0.25cm,
    database aspect ratio=0.35,
    database top segment/.style={
        database top segment style/.append style={#1}},
    database middle segment/.style={
        database middle segment style/.append style={#1}},
    database bottom segment/.style={
        database bottom segment style/.append style={#1}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt]
        \node[database,label=below:some label, database middle segment={fill=green}, database bottom segment={draw=none, fill=blue}] {};
        \node[database,label=below:some label,database radius=1cm,database segment height=0.5cm, database top segment={draw=blue,fill=red}] at (3,0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The example above results in:

[image]

Comment: If I try to add a label `\node[below of=database] {some label};`, the position of the label looks incorrect. Is this because of the missing border anchor?

Comment: @Peter when you use `below of=database`, you place the new node at a certain distance from the *center* of the referenced node. With the `positioning` library you can use `below=of database`, which differs slightly in notation but makes sure that the node distance is kept between the *outer dimensions* of the two nodes. To add a label, it is simpler to draw the database node as follows: `\node[database,label=below:some label] {};`. (Both of these things don't bother with the border anchor).

Comment: @Max How can we fill this database with color for each layer and keep the circles' borders to be black?

Comment: @MoustafaMahmoud See my edit.

Comment: @Max You made my day. I will add a special acknowledge to you in my presentation. Thanks,

Comment: A problem with this solution seems to be that the label cannot be word-wrapped via `text width=`.

Comment: @ChristophThiede You can pass `text width=<length>` to the label options between square brackets as follows: `\node[database,label={[text width=2cm]below:some long label that should be wrapped},database radius=1cm,database segment height=0.5cm, database top segment={draw=blue,fill=red}] at (6,0) {};`. Optionally you could add `align=center`.

Answer (score 9):

You are right, a cylinder exists already in `shapes.geometric` and is is very easy to use it to draw a database shape.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{database/.style={cylinder,aspect=0.5,draw,rotate=90,path picture={
\draw (path picture bounding box.160) to[out=180,in=180] (path picture bounding
box.20);
\draw (path picture bounding box.200) to[out=180,in=180] (path picture bounding
box.340);
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[database] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution, even keeping the border anchor intact, but it doesn't scale so nicely (+1 nonetheless for simplicity).

Comment: @MaxSnippe Thanks for the upvote (and of course I upvoted your answer long time ago...;-) I'm not sure, though, I understand your concerns about scaling. At least `\node[database,scale=3] {};` works fine as far as I can see.

Comment: I should have been more specific. I actually meant when setting a different `minimum width`, e.g. `\node[database,minimum width=2cm]{};`. Firstly, this overwrites the `aspect` key I believe, such that the `to[out=180,in=180]` have a different radius then the cylinder itself, and secondly it places the border anchors (`.20`,`.160`, etc.) at completely different places.

Comment: @MaxSnippe Yes, you're right, one should not stretch this ;-)

Comment: This solution is also really nice, but I ended up accepting [the other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/442994/135776), because I went with that one.